# Como puedo pasar esta funcion de mysqli a PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Buenas Tardes mi consulta es la siguiente estoy empezando a usar PDO y quería saber como puedo pasar esta función a código PDO ya que aun no encuentro la solución de mi problema, la función esta
en mysqli y quiero pasarlo a formato PDO ósea los sintaxis de pdo quiero que se vea en el código.

Les paso el código:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en primer lugar el código va como texto, y segundo, creo que existe una pregunta así, no te haría mal buscar un poco

Comment: Bueno, la verdad no comprendo bien la consulta, o sea, no hay un problema específico que podamos responder, de todas formas, lo que sí queda muy claro es que querés implementar PDO, bueno, podrías leer entre otros lugares, la documentación oficial de PHP que tiene un apartado al respecto; https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php